# Bit manipulation tilde

Tags: c++, bit, tilde

I understand that tilde flips every bits, but if I do `int num = ~0` 
Why the result is `num = -1` , neither max value of `int` or `unsigned int`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 1):

But it is the max value of `unsigned`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  std::cout << ( unsigned(-1) == std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() )
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/y4JuFe

Comment: But if I do int unsigned int num = ~0, the result is num = 4294967295, I think this shall be the max of unsigned int

Comment: Unsigned 4294967295 and signed -1 have the same bit pattern.